# How to ignore defaultLocale in ResourceBundle.getBundle?

Tags: java, locale, resourcebundle

Currently i am learning i18n and found that the Locale returned by

```
Locale.getDefault()
```

influence the look up process for the resource. The example is taken from [The Java™ Tutorials - A Quick Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/quick.html) slightly modified:

**org.i18n.I18NSample**

```
package org.i18n;

import java.util.*;

public class I18NSample {

    static public void main(String[] args) {

        String language;
        String country;

        if (args.length != 2) {
            language = new String("en");
            country = new String("US");
        } else {
            language = new String(args[0]);
            country = new String(args[1]);
        }

        Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
        System.out.println("default language = " + defaultLocale.getLanguage()
                  + "; default country = " + defaultLocale.getCountry());

        Locale inputLocale = new Locale(language, country);
        System.out.println("input language = " + inputLocale.getLanguage()
                  + "; input country = " + inputLocale.getCountry());

        ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", inputLocale);
        Locale bundleLocale = messages.getLocale();
        System.out.println("bundle language = " + bundleLocale.getLanguage()
                  + "; bundle country = " + bundleLocale.getCountry());

        System.out.println(messages.getString("greetings"));
        System.out.println(messages.getString("inquiry"));
        System.out.println(messages.getString("farewell"));
    }
}
```

defined default resource **MessagesBundle.properties**

```
greetings = Hello.
farewell = Goodbye.
inquiry = How are you?
```

and 3 additional resource files

**MessagesBundle_de_DE.properties**

```
greetings = Hallo.
farewell = Tschüß.
inquiry = Wie geht's?
```

**MessagesBundle_en_US.properties**

```
greetings = Hi.
farewell = Bye-bye.
```

**MessagesBundle_fr_FR.properties**

```
greetings = Bonjour.
farewell = Au revoir.
inquiry = Comment allez-vous?
```

until now everything is O.K. `java -jar I18nFirstTest.jar fr FR` gives:

```
default language = pl; default country = PL
input language = fr; input country = FR
bundle language = fr; bundle country = FR
Bonjour.
Comment allez-vous?
Au revoir.
```

`java -jar I18nFirstTest.jar nl NL` gives:

```
default language = pl; default country = PL
input language = nl; input country = NL
bundle language = ; bundle country =
Hello.
How are you?
Goodbye.
```

now, I add the following resource file **MessagesBundle_pl_PL.properties**

```
farewell = Do widzenia.
greetings = Dzie\u0144 dobry.
inquiry = \u0104\u0105\u0106\u0107\u0118\u0119\u0141\u0142\u0143\u0144Óó\u015A\u015B\u0179\u017A\u017B\u017C
```

and there the problem arises `java -jar I18nFirstTest.jar nl NL` gives:

```
default language = pl; default country = PL
input language = nl; input country = NL
bundle language = pl; bundle country = PL
Dzień dobry.
ĄąĆćĘęŁłŃńÓóŚśŹźŻż
Do widzenia.
```

the reason **pl_PL** is set in the bundle is described here [public static ResourceBundle getBundle(String baseName, Locale locale, ClassLoader loader)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Character.html) - extract:

```
If no matching resource bundle is found, the default control's
getFallbackLocale method is called, which returns the current
default locale. A new sequence of candidate locale names is
generated using this locale and and searched again, as above.
```

and the default locale is indeed **pl_PL**, but that is **NOT** what I want to get by the design --> there is default resource, right?

**QUESTION:**
How do I remove that functionality of the `getBundle` method, that it processes the second look up using my default Locale?

I don't want to change my locale to `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "GB"))` because it will influence the functionality of other modules

Switching between locales may also not be thread-safe operation (right?)

```
...
    Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "GB"));
    ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", inputLocale);
    Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale);
...
```

So what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

When loading a resource bundle Java basically first checks if there is a bundle for the requested locale, then if there is a bundle for the default locale and if neither of those is present it returns the base bundle (bundle for `Locale("")`).

As stated in the fragment of documentation you quoted the default locale is provided by the `getFallbackLocale()` method of control. `ResourceBundle` provides a static `Control` class that controls the process. It is used by default when loading a `ResourceBundle` but you can provide your own implementation of `Control`as well.

What should suffice in your case is:

```
public class ModifiedControl extends ResourceBundle.Control {

    @Override
    public Locale getFallbackLocale( String aBaseName, Locale aLocale ) {
        if( aBaseName == null || aLocale == null ) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Because the method returns null `ResourceBundle` will return the default resource.

> [...]
>   5. The control.getFallbackLocale method is called to get a fallback locale (alternative to the current target locale) to try further
>   finding a resource bundle. If the method returns a non-null locale, it
>   becomes the next target locale and the loading process starts over
>   from Step 3. Otherwise, if a base bundle was found and put on hold in
>   a previous Step 5, it is returned to the caller now. Otherwise, a
>   MissingResourceException is thrown.
>   [...]
>   source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.util.ResourceBundle.Control)

Then you must simply provide an instance of your modified control when loading a resource bundle.

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", inputLocale, new ModifiedControl() );
```